# Are there any anime/manga award ceremonies outside of Japan?

Tags: events

Anime is now consumed internationally at a large scale, and there are many non-Japanese companies that make their living off of this audience.

Because of this, I've been wondering - **are there any anime or manga award ceremonies (for the shows themselves OR for anime-related companies, Western or not) that are based outside of Japan?**

* looking for examples rather than an exhaustive list

** anime-specific (I know there are general animation awards that can be won by anime)

*** of a reasonable scale (i.e. a formal event)

Comment: Seeing as Korea also makes anime, it seems like there would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after searching the web for a while, the largest one I was able to find is the [American Anime Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Anime_Awards), which was only hosted once on the New York comic-con in 2007. Aside from this, I was unable to find any full-scaled events. However, you might be able to find smaller awards or contests in different countries, for example I came upon [this](http://www.animecon.nl/program/events/contests/dutch-manga-awards) contest which is a part of Dutch animecon.

> I know there are general animation awards that can be won by anime

I think this is the main reason why you will not find any full-scale awards outside of Japan (Japan is a special case, obviously). However lot of major film festivals will most likely have awards for "best animated film" (or something similar), where anime entries will be able to compete -  for example, you will often see anime in the list of Academy Award for Best Animated Feature nominees.